# Global declaration in iOS

Tags: iphone

i have this code for storing information about username,password,costomerkey etc etc in .h file

```
extern NSString * const consumerKey;
extern NSString * const consumerSecret;
extern NSString * const userStoreUri;
extern NSString * const noteStoreUriBase;
extern NSString * const shardId;
extern NSString * const  username; 
extern NSString * const  password;
```

in .m file

```
 NSString * const consumerKey  = @"mynote";
    NSString * const consumerSecret = @"45fv66gtt";
    NSString * const username = @"john55";// need to be dynamic instead of john55 textfiledusername.text;
    NSString * const password = @"sjo555";  
    NSString * const userStoreUri = @"https://www.evernote.com/edam/user";
    NSString * const noteStoreUriBase = @"https://www.evernote.com/edam/note/"; 
@implementation evernoteloginpage
```

but here all the values are sttcaly cretae,i want the username and password toy be dynamic,by using text filed .when the login button is clicked it needs to set the text filed values to the string username and password like this.`textfiledusername.text = username` in button click,for the dynamic creation of username and password.
but i put `NSString * const username = textusername.text;` i got errors because
 i put this before implementation method.how t mke this possible? please help me to do this.

Comment: You must write it without "**const**"

Comment: Maybe a `Singleton` design pattern is a solution for you?

Answer (score 0):

You can put objects property to the declaration only in the method or in the procedure. Outside this you can't.